# How to v-bind data correctly from mutation to child component correctly on Vue 3 with Typescript and Composition API?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, clean-architecture

I want to bind data to child-component from mutation. But the data doesn't bind reactively

```
<SelectSearch
  class="my-2"
  @filter="fetchDestinationCity"
  :options="originCityList"
  placeholder="Ketik atau pilih alamat asal"
  keyName="name"
  keyValue="id"
  :isDisabled="isPOS.pos"
  v-model="isPos.originCity"
/>



get isPOS() {
const type = AccountController.accountData.account_type_detail.type;
const district = AccountController.accountData.account_location.district_name;
return type == "pos"
  ? { pos: true, originCity: district }
    : { pos: false, originCity: "" };
  }
```

Comment: Can't really do much with your code example. But generally Vue doesn't let mutate props from child components that were passed from parent. You need to use `emits` to mutate parent data from child. [Documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html)